# Send Mock response for Soap Request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, soap, soap-client

We have created an soap request and sending the request using WebServiceTemplate

```
WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request)
```

As my client is not ready with the server. I am trying to handle this request in my local and planning to post some dummy response.

Can you help me how I can mock this response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CXF, see my JUnit Rule [utility project](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf). It creates an Endpoint using JaxWsServerFactoryBean.